# Plotting results of simulation using listPlot3D

Tags: differential-equations, graphics3d

I am simulating a partial differential equation and I would like to compare the results of Plot3D and listPlot3D. I have gotten the plot3D code to work (not included) however, I am struggling to get the listPlot3D code to run. Here is my latest attempt:

```
eq = {D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 1}] == Cos[x], 
u[0, x] == x^2, u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]};

sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1];


data = Table[ u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}];

ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

But it produces a bunch of errors like:

> Outer::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Outer[List,1.,{1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.,13.,14.,15.,16.,17.,18.,19.,20.,21.}].

The actual picture of the errors is below:

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: whoops that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Plot3D`

```
sol = u /. First@NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1];
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Or

```
data = Table[ sol[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];

ListPlot3D[Transpose@data,
 Mesh -> None,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was using plot3D, but I wanted to see if listPlot3D would get rid of the patches of "dents"/roughness around x = -10. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: See updated answer - it looks indeed nicer :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure *exactly* what you are looking for, but if you want a `ListPlot3D`, perhaps you want

```
data = Flatten[Table[{t, x, u[t, x]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}], 2]
```

Your `data` is just a list of the values of `u[x,t]`, not points in 3-space.